# How to set not to zoom on the mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, meta

Here is the test link:

http://kotechweb.com/ig112

The site now is exactly the way I would like to present, one problem is , if I set to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

on mobile it will zoom

And I tried to set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

However, this will affect the layout and some block will move into wrong position.

So, I wonder how to set not to zoom in mobile by default? Javascript/ jquery is also welcome if meta can not fulfill the needs

Thanks.

**Update:**

Thanks for answering.

Either no scrollable , max scale =1 , min scale = 1, the inital width is still the zoomed version, and can not scale down this time.

Sorry for confusing, the idea is , can the width begin is exactly the width of device? then it is not zoomed

Or what I need to do is to **zoom to the smallest scale**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just removed initial-scale=1 , then it will not zoom

Answer (score 4):

The `user-scalable` parameter should do it.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Otherwise, you can set `minimum-scale` and `maximum-scale` to `1.0`

Answer (score 2):

Using the user-scalable attribute

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```